# Textbook Recommendation for Brushing up on Elementary Freshman/Sophomore Level Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

As is the case with most students (I suppose), I seem to have lost touch with the do doing some "basic" math -- calculating integrals, playing around with matrices and doing some linear algebra etc. -- as I have proceeded through my undergraduate program. To be honest, I didn't practice a whole lost of questions when I took these introductory courses, so I presume that's one source from where this issue stems.

I'm a student of physics with a mathematical leaning. Ideally, I don't want to go through a mathematical methods textbooks for physicists/engineers since they're pretty superficial (at times) and are more like "here's-a-result-now-go-solve-problems." At the same time, I don't think I have the time to sit through very long textbooks, such as James Stewart's *Calculus.*

Any suggestions of textbooks, given my aforementioned concerns, where one can "practice" calculus, linear algebra, complex analysis etc. to stay in touch with the practice of being able to solve in questions in closed form.

Comment: Maybe look at some Schaum's Outline series books (college bookstores and libraries) to see if they would work for you. You can also try tutoring, which incidentally would give you some extra money to buy those Schaum's Outline series books (or something else that catches your eye) that you might be interested in.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro At the end of the day, I do want a good resource/textbook to catch up on the mathematics. I'm not sure if going back to the likes of Calculus by Stewart, Linear Algebra by Strang would be a good idea due to the issue of time. Are Schaum's outline series good "textbooks"? If not, any other suggestions?

Comment: The best suggestion I can think of is to browse the math collection of a university library and see what others suggest. Along the same lines as tutoring, you could see if you can get a job in the math department grading papers for the classes you're interested in -- after carefully working the homework problems yourself (not really needed for this job, but you'd want to do it for the purpose you asked about) and checking over all the students' solutions, making comments and corrections as appropriate, you should know the mathematics involved in that particular assignment very well.